# Could someone help me explain the algebra of these steps

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im confused on the algebraic steps of this simplification. Im looking for someone to explain how the ^2 got removed and how $(2k^2+7k+6)$ gets simplifed to $(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)$ from the image below
[image]

Comment: On the third line $(k+1)$ has been taken out as a factor on the numerator. The remaining factor is in the square bracket. In the final step $2k^2+7k+6$ has been factorised as $(k+2)(2k+3)$.

Comment: In more detail: In the second line, $(k+1)$ appears as a factor of both terms in the numerator.  It is then un-distributed and appears as the factor at the front of the numerator in the third line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is a restatement of the comments, to help remove this Question from the Unanswered queue)

- In the second line, $(k+1)$ appears as a factor of both terms in the numerator. It is then un-distributed and appears as the factor at the front of the numerator in the third line.
- In the final step $2k^2+7k+6$ has been [factored](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:factor-quadratics-strategy/a/factoring-quadratics-in-any-form) as $(k+2)(2k+3)$.